# search an array for a number 10 times and calculate the time for each search

Tags: java, loops, binary-search, linear-search

I want to create an array with 10 million numbers from 1- 10 million. I am using a loop to populate the array (increment of 1). Now I want to search the first array 10 times (create a loop to search 10 times)with a second array of numbers (e.g. int arr2[] = {10, 20, .....}. I then want to calculate the time it took for each search, the average and standard deviation and then print the the result in a table.
the table I will just print with "\t"
this is what I have so far:

```
public class LinearBinearySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("By linear search:\n" + check[k] + " found at index " + found +"\t");
        System.out.println("Table below shows result:");
        System.out.print("First run\tSecond run\tThird run\tFourth run\tFifth run\tSixth run\tSeventh run\tEight run\tNinth run\tTenth run\tAverage \tStandard deviation\n");

        arrPoplte();

        linSrch();


        loopCheck();
    }


static int i = 0;
static int k = 0;
static int[]Arr = new int[10000000];
static int[]check = {500, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 5000000, 7000000, 10000000};
public static void loopCheck(){


}

public static void arrPoplte(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i ++){
        Arr[i] = i + 1;

    }

}
static int found = 0;
static long start;
static long end;
public static void linSrch(){



    long sum = 0;
    long sumSquare = 0;

        for(int c = 0; c < 10 ; c++){

        start = System.nanoTime();
        while(Arr[i]<check.length){
            if(Arr[i]==check[i])
                System.out.print(Arr[i]);
            end = System.nanoTime();
             sum += end - start;
                sumSquare += Math.pow(end - start, 2);
        }









    System.out.print((end - start) +"\t\t");
        }
        double average = (sum * 1D) / 10;
        double variance = (sumSquare * 1D) / 10 - Math.pow(average, 2);
        double std = Math.sqrt(variance);
        System.out.print(average +"\t\t" + std + "\n");
```

but 1. I think its too much codes and 2. I cannot loop through the second array to use the value for the first on.

This is my desired output:
500 was found at whatever index 
1st run   2nd run.............10th run    Avg       Standard dev.
x ms       y ms                z ms      av ms      whatever it is

how can I tweak my code to produce the desired output.

I apologize in advance for such a long question and I hope someone can help me
Thank you

Comment: Please indent your code to make it readable, even by you. And respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter, and whole words are used: `populateArray` and not `arrPoplte`, `linearSearch` and not `linSrch`. This may sound unimportant, but it's incredibly important. If your brain has to translate everything and look for opening and closing braces, it can't concentrate on the logic.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I'm kinda new at this. I will do that and repost. Hope you can help me

Comment: Okay. Just spent like 10 minutes reformatting the code just so Eclipse could even try to compile it. There's something wrong with the searching function as well, not just the printing system...

Answer (score 0):

To put it quite simply, there is a lot of stuff wrong with your code. First thing is that it doesn't work on my computer (and won't even compile, given what you pasted onto SO).

So, I rewrote it because I couldn't make heads or tails of what is going on. I've also included comments which I hope are helpful.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SearchBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SearchBenchmark sBenchmark = new SearchBenchmark(); // I don't like the word 'static'. You can disregard all of
                                                                // this
        sBenchmark.init();  // Execute the meat of the program
    }

    private void init() {

        int maxAttempts = 10;   // Set how many times we're doing this

        long[] times = new long[maxAttempts];   // Create something to hold the times which we want to run this
        int[] range = populateArray(10000000);  // Initialise the array with the given range

        Random rand = new Random(); // Create random integer generator
        int[] target = new int[maxAttempts];    // Create an array filled with the target of our searches

        // Populate target with random integers, since having preselected ones will bias your sample.
        for (int x = 0; x < target.length; x++) {
            target[x] = rand.nextInt((10000000 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        }

        // Execute the attempts
        for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {

            long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // Starting time

            int result = search(range, target[attempt]);    // Find it
            if (result == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("It's not in the range.");   // Make sure we actually have it
            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();   // Ending time
            long elapsed = endTime - startTime; // Difference
            times[attempt] = elapsed;   // Save the elapsed time
        }

        // ==== Summarisation section ====

        // Print out times and produce a sum
        int sum = 0;
        for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {
            sum = (int) (sum + times[attempt]);
            System.out.println("Attempt " + attempt + " took " + times[attempt] + " nanoseconds");
        }

        // Print out average
        int average = sum / maxAttempts;
        System.out.println("Average time: " + average + " nanoseconds");

        // Create and print the standard deviation
        int sumSquares = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < maxAttempts; x++) {
            sumSquares = (int) (sumSquares + Math.pow(times[x] - average, 2));
        }

        int std = (int) Math.sqrt(sumSquares / maxAttempts);
        System.out.println("Standard deviation: " + std + " nanoseconds");
    }

    /**
     * Searches for the target within a range of integers
     *
     * @param range to search within
     * @param target to find
     * @return the target if it exists, otherwise, 0
     */
    private int search(int[] range, int target) {
        for (int x : range) {   // Iterate through the entire range
            if (x == target) { return x; }  // If you found it, return it and stop searching
        }

        return 0;   // If we can't find it, return 0
    }

    /**
     * Creates and populates an array from 0 to a variable <code>i</code>
     *
     * @param i the maximum amount to which the array should be populated
     * @return an array with the range contained within
     */
    private int[] populateArray(int i) {
        int[] array = new int[i];   // Create an array of the size indicated
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {   // Populate that array with the range desired
            array[x] = x;
        }
        return array;   // Give it back
    }
}
```